# Change the day of a range of dates in column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite new in vba and I would need to change the day of a range of dates (until last row of the column) based on condition.
For example, in column A i have a huge list of dates, in column B I have the name of the supplier, and I need to modify the date in a new colum (C) based on the name of the supplier. If supplier name is A, then change the day of the date to 25.

I have this code and it works for one line, I would need it for all the column.

```
Sub testdata()
Dim date1 As Date

date1 = [a2]

m1 = Month(date1)
d1 = Day(date1)
y1 = Year(date1)

testdate = DateSerial(y1, m1, 25)

Range("c2").Value = testdate


End Sub
```

Anyone could help me with this?

Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  This is not a coding service.  You should try to solve the problem yourself and post code samples when you run into specific problems.

Comment: Loop trough column A with a For loop. Use If to check if column B is supplier A and if true, modify column C. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Why don't you just use formulas for that? Would be easier and probably faster than VBA. Any specific reason why there is the need of VBA?

Comment: I would need this to be automated as is a long procés and would need a macro to complete all the steps in excel

Comment: You can also write a formula with a macro. So this still might be faster with formulas then.